# two differenrt styles for one application angular 6

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

This is repeated questions already but I have tried all ways one of them is worked but it seems not a good one I wanna have two different styles sheet and also different scripts the first one for user pages and the other with admin panel each one has it is own styles and scripts and images how can I separated between these different styles I have to add the main one in index.html using ids and then change ids value deepened in the page layout  but it seems not a good way as I have a multi error in console that unknown links of users and case of admin and vise verse 
my trial is 
This is my head

```
 <!--custom css-->
 <link id="Usertheme" rel="stylesheet" href="">
 <!--Bootstrap css-->
 <link id="Userbootstrap" rel="stylesheet" href="">
 <!--Magnific popup css-->
 <link id="Userpopup" rel="stylesheet" href="">
 <!--Themify icon css-->
  <link id="Usericons" rel="stylesheet" href="">
 <!--animated css-->
 <link id="Useranimate" rel="stylesheet" href="">
 <!--ytplayer css-->
 <link id="UserYTPlayer" rel="stylesheet" href="">
 <!--Owl carousel css-->
 <link id="Usercarousel"  rel="stylesheet" href="">
 <link id="Userdefault" rel="stylesheet" href="">
 <!--responsive css-->
 <link id="Userresponsive" rel="stylesheet" href="">

 <!--admin-->
    <link id="adminapp" href="" rel="stylesheet">
    <link id="adminmaterialize" href="" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Theme style. You can choose a theme from css/themes instead of get all themes -->
    <link id="adminalltheme" href="" rel="stylesheet" />
```

in the admin page ts

```
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document, private router: Router, private service: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.document.getElementById('Usertheme').setAttribute('href', './assets/css/adminstyle.css');
    this.document.getElementById('adminapp').setAttribute('href', './assets/css/app.min.css');
    this.document.getElementById('adminmaterialize').setAttribute('href', './assets/js/bundles/materialize-rtl/materialize-rtl.min.css');
    this.document.getElementById('adminalltheme').setAttribute('href', './assets/css/styles/all-themes.css');

    this.service.getUserProfile().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.userDetails = res;
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      },
    );
  }
```

and in user pages I change the links

what is the best way to handle this part with two separated styles

Comment: Have you tried @Component(){ temmplateUrl: 'admin.component.html', styleUrls: [ './assets/css/adminstyle.css' ] } like this?

Comment: No I am beginner and where can I put my scripts

Comment: OK. Don't worry. There must be certainly a solution. Angular let you define style sources inside a component if you like. If you don't define any style source in a component, Angular use resources only defined in index.html. Now, in admin.component.ts file, you should define its own style sources. Look what's here: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#non-css-style-files

Comment: thanks for your comment I have try it now but the style became not good and most of the styles not working despite the path  is correct with others files in the same folder

Comment: and what about js files

Comment: OK. Think simple. Separate your CSS files into groups. Call 1st css group from admin.component.ts and other components that are similar admin component. On the other side, call 2nd group of CSS files from the other type of component which have entirely different appearance. As for the index.html, define only common CSS files if any. If this solution works fine, I can help much more detail if you stack.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211808/discussion-between-ludeveloper-and-mr-alaa).